# 'helloworld.pyx' doesn't match any files

Tags: python, cython

I am a beginner in python and I have just got familiar with cython as well. I am using Anaconda on Windows 64-bit. I am trying to run the "helloworld" example as follows:

1- I build a helloworld.pyx file containing:

```
    print("Hello World")
```

2- I build a setup.py file containing:

```
   from distutils.core import setup
   from Cython.Build import cythonize

   setup(name='Hello world app',ext_modules=cythonize("helloworld.pyx"),)
```

But I get the following error:

```
   'helloworld.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

Could you please tell me what should I do now? Where should I save these two files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-distutils_preprocessing

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'MyProject',
  ext_modules = cythonize(["*.pyx"]),
)
```

Looks like cythonize accepts a list of strings, but you're providing a string.